# Qt SSl Error (QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method)

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, openssl, qsslsocket

I get the below error when I use setUrl("https://www.bing.com") of QWebView:

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView();
view->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.bing.com"));
view->show();
```

**Error:**

- QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
- QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
- QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
- QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method

Im using qt5.2.1(x86), windows 8 64 bit OS pc. How to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe bug in Qt: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36433?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel ?

Comment: You could try to use much recent version of Qt, but I am not sure it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The version of openssl you have installed is too old. Install version 1.0.0 or newer (preferably the latest version). If those methods can't be resolved (but you still have some SSL support) then Qt is only able to find an older version such as openssl 0.9.8 which is too old to support these methods.